# Is it possible to have multiple project types (target platforms) in one Xcode 4 workspace?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

In Xcode 4 I want to use the workspace to have multiple project types and have these projects reference static libraries which will hold common functions like data access code etc.

Is it therefore possible (or correct) to have a Mac/iPhone/iPad project in the same workspace and have each reference static libraries (also in the workspace) just like you can do with a Microsoft Visual Studio Solution.

Or is it that a workspace should contain one application type, say a Mac application, and then include the static libraries into each workspace, thus ending up with 3 workspace projects one for each of my target platforms?

Many thanks.

Comment: I decided to use the new workspace but not to share libs at this point due to the static/dynamic issue highlighted below. However it will be more useful when sharing for iPhone/iPad just not the Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix any projects whatsoever. There's no limitation or warning against different platform types - in fact, Workspaces are there with this (shared library between a Mac OS and iOS application, each in its own project) in mind.

The only thing you need to worry about is how to manage your build schemes. That is, do you want to build all products of all projects each time this scheme is run, and which executable to run among all those projects when you hit "run", etc.

Comment: Thanks Joshua will give this ago today and update the question with my results.

Comment: It's important to note when I say "any projects whatsoever", I mean it. They can even be 100% unrelated to one-another (though it'd be pointless to use a workspace in the case).

Comment: I looked into this further and set up a workspace with a Mac,iPad and iPhone app and a cocoa library project to use as a data access layer. However it seems that the iPad/iPhone projects require the data access library to be a static whereas the Mac should utilise it as a dynamic library to maximise performance. How can you get around this problem when using the same library in different projects within a workspace?

Comment: You are correct in what you are saying so have accepted this as my answer as anybody else looking at this question will probably use 99% of what you have said. Also it did go a long way to helping me find the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This might help [Building Static Libraries to Share Code on iPhone AND Mac OS X Projects](http://zetetic.net/blog/2010/02/15/building-static-libraries-to-share-code-on-iphone-and-mac-os-x-projects/) and another similar question here on SO [How do you create hybrid XCode projects for Mac & iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443074/how-do-you-create-hybrid-xcode-projects-for-mac-iphone)

Comment: Thanks for the links and have already read the questions. I don't have a problem creating libraries and linking them in the old Xcode but would like more information on how best to do this with Xcode 4 and the new workspace feature.