# Adding an iOS version to a Mac app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, macos

I've been searching around for an answer for this for a while and have yet to find an answer. I already have a Mac app as an Xcode project and that is working great. Now I want to make an iOS version of the app. What would you recommend as the best way to do this? There are several Cocoa classes that will be shared between the two versions as well as some resources files (images, strings). It seems like the best way to do this would be to have two separate Xcode projects and add them as sub-projects, but I can't seem to figure that out.

Thanks for any help.

P.S. I'm using Xcode 4.x

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you create hybrid XCode projects for Mac & iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/443074/how-do-you-create-hybrid-xcode-projects-for-mac-iphone)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. Its the same question, but I didn't find the answers very helpful. It just says what to do, not how to do it.

Comment: Alright, well I was just throwing that out there. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing, which seems to work, is to just have two completely separate projects and keep the shared files in some folder on my computer. Then add the shared files to each project and not select the copy items to destination folder option. This way I can edit the files in one project and the changes will appear in the other project.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like you want to add a second target to your project. See screenshot "2 targets, multiple platforms"

[image]

You'll see at the bottom of your project page an "`Add Target`" button(Visible in screen shot). It will allow you to create a new target for your project. Both will be available to compile and run separately but they will share files.

Alternatively, you could use a workspace with two or three projects.
[image]

One project for each target and optionally one to house the shared classes. This requires adding the shared classes to each project. Simply drag from the container project to the other two projects to link the classes.

Comment: OK, I have everything set up like you do in the second screenshot, and I have added the container project to both other projects. But I can't seem to add the shared classes to the other projects. When I drag the files to the compile sources build phase they show up in red text (meaning that Xcode could not find the file).

Comment: I found a solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to do it.. but if you see this project - https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

It have iOS and mac projects in a single directory you can open either iOS project or mac project also they are sharing same class to stream audio...

I am checking this in more details and will post if I find something...

Edit 1 -

Here are some resouces you may find useful -
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/12397

[Same code base for iPhone/Desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617166/same-code-base-for-iphone-desktop-app)

> Usually i create Mac project in other directory and then copy needed
>   files to the folder with iOS project. You can share all sources,
>   probably even pch, but i prefer use one pch for mac and one for iOS.
>   Moving Info.plist from Mac i rename it to Info-Mac.plist and change
>   this in MYPPROJECTNAME-Mac.xcodeproj
>
> Pretty simple, but you add any files to your project - you need to add
>   them again in Mac.xcodeproj. Probably there must be a way of having
>   Mac & iOS Targets in one xcodeproj, but i failed to do this in XCode3,
>   so i use two xcodeproj.